# Jquery Datatables Error onclick

Tags: jquery, datatables

this is my function:

```
function getUsersOnDatabase(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetUsersOnDatabaseServlet",
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonString = JSON.parse(data);
                    var $row;
                    //$("#users_table > tbody").find("tr").remove();

                    table.fnClearTable();

                    $.each(jsonString, function(k, v) { 
                        var newRow = table.fnAddData(['<i class="fa fa-times" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:eraseUser('+v.id+')"></i>', '<a href="javascript:openEditUserForm('+v.id+')">'+v.id+'</a>', v.name, v.div, v.type]);
                        console.log("newRow "+newRow);
                        var oSettings = table.fnSettings();
                        console.log("oSettings "+oSettings);
                        var nTr = oSettings.aoData[ newRow[0] ].nTr;
                        console.log("nTr "+nTr);
                        nTr.id = v.id;
                        console.log("nTr.id "+nTr.id);
                    });

                    if($("#users_table > tbody > tr").length == 0){
                        $row = $('<tr><td colspan="4" class="text-center"><%=list.get("edit.users.table.null")%></td></tr>');
                        $('#users > tbody:last').append( $row);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Explaining what's the purpose of this function, i'm creating a table dinamically with Datatables plugin(as image below). But the first two columns, suposed to when i click on them, go to a function and do a action, like in the first column, clicking "x" would eliminate that user and on the second column would open a form below the table to edit user, that auto-fill the input fields with the data from that user with a ajax request. the thing is when i click on the "x", i get always the same error:

> TypeError: 'insertCell' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface HTMLTableRowElement.

and when i click on a field of the second column, supposedly to edit, when that field is not only numbers, get the same error of the first column. For example, in the image below, if i click on of the 3 first rows to edit, it's all ok, but on the other rows that have letters, gives me that error.
[image: Error]

really stuck in here, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
this is my html of the table(included in my jsp file):

```
<div class="ibox-content">                      
   <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="users_table">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th class="colsm-1"><%out.println(list.get("edit.users.table.first.row")); %></th> 
                    <th><%out.println(list.get("edit.users.table.second.row")); %></th>   
                    <th><%out.println(list.get("edit.users.table.third.row")); %></th>
                    <th><%out.println(list.get("edit.users.table.forth.row")); %></th>
                    <th><%out.println(list.get("edit.users.table.fifth.row")); %></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4" id="showFormButton">
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1" type="submit" onclick="openForm();"><% out.println(list.get("edit.users.form.button.text"));%></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the json returned from ajax request:
[image: json_response]

And the version of DataTables i'm using is 1.10.12
**EDIT2:**
And this is my function eraseUser where i want to delete a user when click on the "x".

> ```
> function eraseUser(id){
>           $.ajax({
>               type: "POST",
>               url: "DeleteAppUserAjaxService",
>               data: {"userid":id},
>               success: function (data) {
>                   var jsonString = JSON.parse(data);
>                   if(jsonString.resposta)
>                   {
>                         var table=$("#users_table").find("#"+id).remove();
>                         if($("#users_table > tbody > tr").length == 0){
>                             $row = $('<tr><td colspan="4" class="text-center"><%=list.get("edit.users.table.null")%></td></tr>');
>                             $('#users_table > tbody:last').append($row);
>                         }
>                         swal({
>                             title: '<%=list.get("edit.users.remove.success.swal.title")%>',
>                             timeout: 2000,
>                             type: "success"
>                         });
>                     }else{
>                         swal({
>                             title: '<%=list.get("edit.users.remove.error.swal.title")%>',
>                             text:'<%=list.get("edit.users.remove.error.swal.text")%>',
>                             timeout: 2000,
>                             type: "error"
>                         });
>                     }
>               }
>           });
>       }
> ```

to analyze my jquery code, i posted all my jquery code on this fiddle:
[fiddle jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/2ww5sot9/)

Comment: If you are on version 1.10 of DataTables you are really fighting the library here by manually managing everything.  Could you post you javascript, HTML, and a sample of your returned JSON?  The immediate problem is likely in your click event handlers but can't say without seeing the code.

Comment: @Aliester 
 
Already edited adding that info that you asked

Comment: Where is the code for the "onClick" event handlers?

Comment: @Aliester edited again, sry my mistake. just posted the code of one function because the problem is the same on both, so if someone help me on the erase, on the edit will be the same, i think

Comment: Besides the possible implicit global variable declaration for $row I don't see a problem in the erase function.  But there is a function call to "swal" which is not included in the question.  If you can could you just put all your javascript for this page into one code block.  It is hard evaluating what is going on absent context.

Comment: it's a very big file, with jsp and javascript. Swal is a plugin for alert messages, the problem is not there. the thing is if i do an alert right after the ajax request,after the sucess line, still don't do the alert, like if it didn't even entered on the request,

Comment: @Aliester posted the link of a fiddle where are all my jquery functions

Comment: This error occurs from the `ajax` can you try adding this to your ajax calls and see if it resolves the issue.  `processData: false, contentType: false`

Comment: @RajshekarReddy 
 
it gives this error: "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableRowElement]". But i give a test and print my var id that my function eraser receives and it's not only the id, it's [object HTMLTableRowElement]. if i printf id.cells[0].innerHTML it prints the element i, like this:
"<i class="fa fa-times" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:eraseUser(test)"></i>". the problem is on the var, don't know why is passing all the element